# Mapbox and OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

I'm new in osm and mapbox, I've read that mapbox is powered by open data from OpenStreetMap [in this documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/help/osm-and-mapbox/) , But why mapbox is enriched with data compared to osm? Can I have more explanation about it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the page you linked:

> Data for Mapbox Streets comes primarily from OpenStreetMap, with
>   Natural Earth and our own tweaks used for some parts.

They combine OSM data with other sources for their Mapbox Streets product.

Comment: Thank you for replying @scai so this is the reason why mapbox is very expensive :) .